# Building R package krb5 from source

Tags: c, r, kerberos, rcpp, devtools

I'm trying to install the package krb5 from source available on rforge [rforge](https://www.rforge.net/krb5/git.html).

To do so I use the following command within RStudio (1.0.136) with R (3.3.1)  on Windows 7.

```
install.packages("krb5",,"http://rforge.net/",type="source")
```

Unfortunately this results in the following error:

```
* installing *source* package 'krb5' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c k.c -o k.o
k.c:1:18: fatal error: krb5.h: No such file or directory
 #include <krb5.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [k.o] Error 1
Warnung: Ausführung von Kommando 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="krb5.dll" OBJECTS="k.o"' ergab Status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'krb5'
* removing 'C:/Users/Fabian Desktop/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/krb5'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\User\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCOnG2U/downloaded_packages/krb5_0.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘krb5’ had non-zero exit status
```

It seems as if the file "krb5.h" wasn't found. This makes sense since the package builds on MIT's Kerberos project available [here](https://github.com/krb5/krb5).

The problem I am facing is that I've never built a C-project. Therefore I do not know how to "combine" the two projects or where to add the MIT-project to the R package such that it is available for the R package when building it. A short step by step guide I should take to make this working is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I know nothing about the *specifics* of package krb5. But read on ...

A common pattern with Rcpp package is that they are *interfaces* between R on the one hand, and an external library on the other hand.

In order to compile code that connects two such worlds, you need header files and libraries *from both*.  R covers its own side.

But krb5 likely only gives you the ability to talk Kerboros backends *provided you have Kerberos (development) software installed*.  In other words krb5 is likely a gateway Kerberos, not Kerberos itself.

Comment: Thank you @Dirk Eddelbuettel. Yes a 'gateway' is what I am looking for, that's ok. I wondered if I a) do have to build the external library (on it's own) first and then include the results for the R package built. Or b) (that's what I think) do I include the external source somewhere in the package and build them "together"? If the second is true: do you have a hint where the put the external source files in the package such that they will be found.

Comment: Not sure if you've done this before but generally it is "yes and yes".  The library to link against has to come from somewhere (ie you build it) and the package has to know where it is (on Unix we often use `configure`, on Windows sometimes environment vars are used).   Now: it krb5 said to be buildable on Windows?  Not all packages are ...

Comment: Thanks! The external library is buildable on windows (there's a readme for win), even though this does not seem to be very straight forward (at least for me). Not sure about the R package. In this case I understand your answer as follows: 1. Build the external library (resuting in a dll on windows). 2. This dll and some header-files then need to be available for the R package build. My initial thought that the external (uncompiled) source files can be included in the R package and the the R package is built "directly" seems to be wrong. Right?

Comment: "In theory". In practice the added difficulty is that such software often has build recipes (project file or Makefiles) assuming the Microsoft compiler ... and you cannot (generally) mix and match from R which uses `g++`.

Comment: Ok, I see. I definitely need to read on on this. But I think I got a starting point now. Thank you. I might come back to this issue when having read a good rcpp tutorial.